# If $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, is $E\left(X^2Y\right) = E\left(X^2E\left(Y|X\right)\right)$?

Tags: statistics, expected-value

If $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, does the following hold by law of iterated expectation?

$$E\left(X^2Y\right) = E\left(E\left(X^2Y|X\right)\right) = E\left(X^2E\left(Y|X\right)\right)$$

I'm not too sure about the second equality. The inner expectation is wrt $Y$, holding $X$ constant. However, if $X$ depends on $Y$, does the second equality still hold?

Comment: Well, $X^2$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the expectations exist,

$E[X^2 Y \mid X=x] = E[x^2 Y \mid X=x]= x^2 E[Y \mid X=x]$

so $E[X^2 Y \mid X] = X^2 E[Y \mid X]$

and $E\left[E[X^2 Y \mid X]\right] = E\left[X^2 E[Y \mid X]\right]$